# Escape a variable in bash headache

Tags: linux, bash, variables, escaping

I have created a script in order to automatically convert my Camera's videos from DV to mkv
However, I cannot make it work because it doesn't escape the filename variable correctly.
The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
FTITLE="Tapes 2012, Tape 01 - "
i=1;
find ./ -type f -name "dv_*.dv" | while read fname; do
    CTIME=`stat -c %Y ${fname}`
    FNAME="${FTITLE} - ${i}.mkv"
    /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i ${fname} ${x264_OPTIONS} ./"$FNAME"
    let i=$i+1
done
```

When I run the script, I see the following error:

```
[NULL @ 0x645f40] Unable to find a suitable output format for '2012,'
2012,: Invalid argument
```

Obviously, this is an issue with the script and the filename.
I tried to escape it

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i ${fname} ${x264_OPTIONS} ./"\"$FNAME\""
```

but it did not worked either.

Comment: Have you considered backslashing the spaces in the FTITLE and FNAME declarations?

Comment: Yur quoting of `./"$FNAME"` in the ffmpeg line seems correct to me. It is possible that something with `${fname}` or `${x264_OPTIONS}` is causing the problem. Change the first line to `#!/bin/bash -x` to make bash trace what it's doing.

Comment: You need quotes around `${fname}`, too.

Answer (score 1):

Use more quotes!!! Quote every single variable you have!

Instead of your script, I would have done the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

ftitle="Tapes 2012, Tape 01 - "

x264_options=( your options here in an array that is good practice "and quote if you have an option with spaces" )

shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob

((i=1))

for fname in **/dv_*.dv; do
   [[ -f $fname ]] || continue
   ctime=$(stat -c %Y "$fname")
   fnameuppercase="$ftitle - $i.mkv"
   /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i "$fname" "${x264_options[@]}" ./"$fnameuppercase"
   ((++i))
done
```

There are several differences with yours:

- Use of lower case variable names. It is considered bad practice to use upper case variable names,
- Useless use of `find` here, since your search is so trivial: using bash's glob instead,
- All variables are properly quoted,
- The options are all in an array (good practice! and solves nearly all problems),
- No use of backticks but of `$(...)` command substitution,
- Use of bash's arithmetic operator `((...))`,
- No use of a subshell (in your version, the `while` loop is executed in a subshell)

Comment: And don't forget the exclamation marks!!! They can't really be quoted!!! Unless you use `single quotes`!!! :)

Comment: Also: bad advice. The OP should most likely ***not*** quote `${x264_OPTIONS}`, e.g.

Comment: @sehe: No, using quotes is the best advice! Buy plenty of quotes (they are cheaper when bought in large packs) and **use** them. Regarding options, the only possible clean way is to use arrays (quoted arrays, of course).

Comment: The `${x264_OPTIONS}` has no problem. It is escaped correctly. The output file is the problem.

Comment: @Peter I edited my post. Please review the script given and compare with yours.

Comment: `fnameuppercase` is an odd choice for a variable name. `i=1` does not have to be executed in an arithmetic context.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: Besides the options and the array, I fail to see where I have not properly quoted the variables in my script.

Comment: @glennjackman I know `fnameuppercase` is an odd choice. I just wanted to stick as close to the OP as I could, without using uppercase variable names. Regarding `((i=1))`, this is just to make it clear that the variable `i` will always be used in arithmetic context; sure `i=1` will do as well.

Comment: @Peter I guess it's the `${fname}` in the lines `CTIME=\`stat -c %Y ${fname}\`` and `/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i ${fname} ...` that is are quoted.

Comment: `declare -i i` would be better to ensure integer-ness.

Comment: @glennjackman no need to ensure anything. If you have a better solution, please post it.

Comment: Well, it seems that the quotation of fname inside the stat was the problem.

Comment: Then again, the problem is not solved. From command line it's OK, but from the script it, it is not.
It seems that the arithmetic operator is not working properly.

Comment: @Peter are you using bash or another shell?

Comment: @Peter, then it should work! Post your script (edit your OP and post it at the end) and tell us what (and where it) doesn't work.